# Shell script invocation error with MailCore

Tags: ios, xcode, mailcore

I am attempting to use MailCore in an app, I have gotten the project from Github and followed the directions at http://libmailcore.com/.

Everything seems to import correctly, however when I try to build the project I am getting the Shell Script Invocation Error Can't exec '/usr/bin/make' (No such file or directory) for the cyrus-sasl and openssl projects included within MailCore. Any advice would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what it was, I had to enable command line tools under:
XCode > Preferences > Downloads > Components > command line tools.

Also, It's not listed in the MailCore tutorial, but to get git support in Terminal I found this website for a walkthrough 
http://vandadnp.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/git-from-command-line-after-installing-xcode-on-os-x-lion/

Comment: Hi, sadly this doesn't work for me on XCode 6. Are there any advices? Thanks!